# Adding Nano S Ledger hardware wallet to Parity wallet

Tags: wallet, ethereum

I used to have this here, but accidently told it to forget the contract.  Now I want to add it back, but it doesn't show up.  I have followed these steps:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Ledger-Nano-S

Comment: never could figure this out.  I started to access my wallet with other tools such as MetaMask